# fireevent problem in react-testing-library

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library

I am using react-testing-library for my react app.
In one test case, I need to fill some value in a textbox and focusout.

Here is the test script -

```
it('searchbox wrapper',async()=>{
    let wrapper=getSearchBoxWrapperInstance('')
    let inputBox=wrapper.findByTestId('inputText');
    inputBox.value='12345';
    fireEvent(inputBox,'focusOut');

})
```

I am getting the following error when I run the test case -

```
TypeError: element.dispatchEvent is not a function

  79 |     let inputBox=wrapper.findByTestId('inputText');
  80 |     inputBox.value='12345';
> 81 |     fireEvent(inputBox,'focusOut');
     |     ^
  82 |     //fireEvent('Blur',
  83 | 
  84 |     //await (() => wrapper.getByText('')))

  at fireEvent (node_modules/dom-testing-library/dist/events.js:533:18)
```

Please let me know if I can provide further information

Answer (score 8):

I'm assuming `getSearchBoxWrapperInstance` returns the result of `render`.

Try if this works:

```
it('searchbox wrapper',async()=>{
  let wrapper=getSearchBoxWrapperInstance('')
  let inputBox=wrapper.findByTestId('inputText');
  fireEvent.change(inputBox, { target:  { value: '12345' } });
  fireEvent.focusOut(inputBox);
  // In alternative you could try fireEvent.blur
})
```

It's also possible that `findByTestId` doesn't find your element. Try to log it out to see if that's the case or use `getByTestId` which errors our if the element is not found.

Comment: I am getting this error now - "The given element does not have a value setter", at this line - fireEvent.change(inputBox, { target:  { value: '1234567' } });

Comment: Are you sure `inputBox` is what you expect it to be?

Comment: Is there a way to print log using this library... I could not find enough docs on this

Comment: `const { debug } = render()` by default if you call `debug()` you will get the whole DOM printed. You can also to `debug(inputBox)`

Answer (score 2):

```
// import ing userevent
import userEvent from '@testing-library/user-event';
// detecting the input in component by the placeholder name
const input = screen.queryByPlaceholderText('input placeholder 
name');
// entering data in the userEvent
userEvent.type(input,'typing some value into the input');
// invoking blur functiuonality.
fireEvent.blur(input);
```

Comment: Welcome to SO? Can you explain what your problem is in the question?

Answer (score 0):

By Writing

```
const inputElement = screen
      .getByTestId('textarea-provided-test-id')
      .querySelector('input');
```

Solved my problem
[Reference link](https://copyprogramming.com/howto/react-testing-library-the-given-element-does-not-have-a-value-setter-when-fireevent-change-on-input-form)